# R: Scraping the hover text title of every cell in a table using rvest

Tags: r

I'm using rvest to scrape data from some javascript tables such as the one here. https://tipping.portadelaidefc.com.au/comp/the-alberton-crowd

As you can see, in this table each cell has a value and also when you hover your mouse over, has another attached value.

I have no problem scraping the table using rvest like so:

```
tips <- read_html("https://tipping.portadelaidefc.com.au/comp/the-alberton-crowd") %>%
   html_table(header=TRUE)
```

But I'm not sure how to scrape the hover values. Can I do that with rvest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could extend/modify the `rvest:::html_table.xml_node` method as follows:
see R comments

```
my_html_table <- function(x, header = NA, trim = TRUE, fill = FALSE, dec = ".", attr_name = ""){
  rows <- html_nodes(x, "tr")
  n <- length(rows)
  cells <- lapply(rows, "html_nodes", xpath = ".//td|.//th")
  ncols <- lapply(cells, html_attr, "colspan", default = "1")
  ncols <- lapply(ncols, as.integer)
  p <- unique(vapply(ncols, sum, integer(1)))
  if (length(p) > 1) {
    if (!fill) {
      stop("Table has inconsistent number of columns. ", 
           "Do you want fill = TRUE?", call. = FALSE)
    }
    else {
      p <- max(p)
    }
  }
############################# 
## The following line is the only one that was changed
############################# 
  values <- lapply(cells, html_attr, attr_name)
# insted of
# values <- lapply(cells, html_text, trim = trim)
  out <- matrix(NA_character_, nrow = n, ncol = p)
  for (i in seq_len(n)) {
    row <- values[[i]]
    ncol <- ncols[[i]]
    col <- 1
    for (j in seq_len(p)) {
      if (j > length(row)) 
        next
      out[i, col] <- row[[j]]
      col <- col + ncol[j]
    }
  }
  if (is.na(header)) {
    header <- all(html_name(cells[[1]]) == "th")
  }
  if (header) {
    col_names <- out[1, , drop = FALSE]
    out <- out[-1, , drop = FALSE]
  } else {
    col_names <- paste0("X", seq_len(ncol(out)))
  }
  df <- lapply(seq_len(p), function(i) {
    utils::type.convert(out[, i], as.is = TRUE, dec = dec)
  })
  names(df) <- col_names
  class(df) <- "data.frame"
  attr(df, "row.names") <- .set_row_names(length(df[[1]]))
  df
}
```

now you can do something like this to "merge" the original data with the tooltip data

```
require(rvest)
doc <- read_html("https://tipping.portadelaidefc.com.au/comp/the-alberton-crowd")
x <- doc %>% html_node("table")
tips <- x %>% my_html_table(attr_name = "title")
dat <- doc %>% html_table() %>% `[[`(1)

tips[,c(1,2,28,29)] <- dat[,c(1,2,28,29)]
tips[1:2,] <- dat[1:2,]
```

which gives you

```
> head(tips)

                         X1          X2 X3      X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10 X11 X12 X13 X14 X15 X16 X17 X18 X19 X20 X21
1 Leaderboard Select Round:        <NA> NA Overall  1  2  3  4  5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17
2                      Rank        Name NA         NA NA NA NA NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
3                         1   Gilly2311 NA    <NA> 11 53 42 72 51  41   5  45  20  75  39   3  41  18  13   7  58
4                         2       Harts NA    <NA> 27 50 56 57 53  28  15  32   8  63  51   1  26  23  21   6  87
5                         3 mygypsyrose NA    <NA>  3 49 64 62 35  61   1  37  20  47  53   9  23   0   7  15  38
6                         4 Scraggie_93 NA    <NA> 19 58 81 32 39  31  12  54  35  44  44  17  25  15   7  16  38
  X22 X23 X24 X25 X26 X27    X28   X29
1  18  19  20  21  22  23             
2  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA Margin Score
3  74  52  11  62  80  15    888   146
4  46  63  18  51  79   4    865   145
5  48  56  19  12  78  11    748   142
6  48  53   7  21  75  11    782   142
```

have a look at *tips* and *dat* to see their results

Answer (score 2):

Or do it with a bit less effort:

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

pg <- read_html("https://tipping.portadelaidefc.com.au/comp/the-alberton-crowd")
tips <- html_table(pg, header=TRUE)[[1]]

bind_rows(lapply(html_nodes(pg, "tbody > tr"), function(x) {
  cbind.data.frame(t(c(html_text(html_nodes(x, "td"))[2], 
                       html_attr(html_nodes(x, "td.tooltip"), "title"))))
}))

##                 1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10    11    12
##             (chr) (chr) (chr) (chr) (chr) (chr) (chr) (chr) (chr) (chr) (chr) (chr)
## 1       Gilly2311    11    53    42    72    51    41     5    45    20    75    39
## 2           Harts    27    50    56    57    53    28    15    32     8    63    51
## 3     mygypsyrose     3    49    64    62    35    61     1    37    20    47    53
## 4     Scraggie_93    19    58    81    32    39    31    12    54    35    44    44
## 5         Deb1967     4    33    54    60    35    72    21    53    20   118    66
## 6        svolaris     6    52    45    76    50    24    19    45    19    64    58
## 7     dazza power    14    56    61    45    62    54     2    64    60    40    36
## 8  Flamingoflames    28    33    35    83    34    76     1    17     9    83    46
## 9    FEARTHEBEARD    27    34    47    59    50    59     6    50     5    54    38
## 10        Jules23    11    35    57    47    42    65    34    38     4    61    37
## ..            ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...
## Variables not shown: 13 (chr), 14 (chr), 15 (chr), 16 (chr), 17 (chr), 18 (chr), 19
##   (chr), 20 (chr), 21 (chr), 22 (chr), 23 (chr), 24 (chr)
```

renaming the columns, changing column type and `cbind`ing it to the main table is also really straightforward.